# code to switch to my website

Tags: iframe, embed, switch-statement

some people puts my website in " iframe" in the forums,blogs,.....

so i want to make code to switch them to my website.

i try this code but its doesn't work :

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$url=curPageURL();

if(!$url == "www.mywebsite.com"){

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.mywebsite.com">';
}
?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this is using JavaScript, using a "frame buster" script such as:

```
<script>
if(top != self) top.location.replace(location);
</script>
```

The code you're using won't work, as server variables such as `SERVER_NAME` are not affected by whether your site is framed or not.